# So, uh, "photo.se" is a valid domain name....

Tags: discussion

It's natural to want to abbreviate the names of Stackexchange sites as `name.se`. But, `.se` is a valid top-level domain, and in fact `photo.se` is [a registered domain running a real web site](http://photo.se/) (although it redirects you elsewhere).

So, in the form of a question:

***Should we stop referring to this site as `photo.se`?***

Comment: Yes, agreed we should avoid this confusion, especially in the interests of newcomers.

Comment: How about: "Should we stop referring to this site as "photo.se"?"

Comment: @Tom: Sure, that'll work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, pretty clearly, the answer is:

We should discourage use of `photo.se` or any other domain-name-like nickname for the site.

Alternatives might be:

- `photo SE`
- `Photo-SE`
- `photo@se` (e-mail-like better than domain-name-like?)
- `stackexchange photo` (yeah okay, not so short)
- `photo stackexchange` (*cough*)
- `"this site"`

(I'm making this post community wiki so other suggestions can be added.)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

It's always sweden, isn't it?

Comment: That's not very nice :-(

Comment: +1 for Awesome. :-)

Comment: @monotux: I think that was from his visit to Finland :D

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, here's the text of the page according to Google Translate:

> Photo.se has grown popular way too
>   fast, with lots of visitors and high
>   picture influx, and is now down for
>   technical maintenance.
>
> Meanwhile, a visit to FotoFynd.se a
>   new advertising market to buy & sell
>   photographic equipment! You moved
>   there automatically within a few
>   seconds.

So maybe there's a prospect for purchasing the domain? Or perhaps they would be willing to put in a note pointing to here.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the confusion, I started abbreviating the site names as:

## Photo-SE

- Webapps-SE
- Gaming-SE
- Cooking-SE

Let's see how that goes. That should avoid the confusion with the domain name, across the network.

Answer (score 1):

Just happened to see this ... over at the TeX sister site, we've been trying to refer to it as "tex.SX" to avoid this problem.  (Being currently resident only a few miles from the border with Sweden, I try not to upset them as much as possible.)

Comment: I think it's probably better to avoid anything domain-name like.